# Saving data to MySQL in 5 seconds with php

Tags: php, mysql, save

There is data from the telephone exchange, data comes with json

Source: https://github.com/verimor/Bulutsantralim-API/blob/master/cdrs.md

there is no problem here.

After that, I want to register the database by checking the data I get from here every 5 seconds.

The json content is constantly updated because it is search continuously.

I'm waiting for your help, thank you very much.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

**Test Code:**

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.bulutsantralim.com/cdrs?key=K12345678-1234-5678-4321-123456789012');

$data = json_decode($json,true);

echo $data['cdrs'][0]['start_stamp'];
echo '-';
echo $data['cdrs'][0]['direction'];
echo '-';
echo  $data['cdrs'][0]['caller_id_number'];
echo '-';
echo  $data['cdrs'][0]['caller_id_number'];
echo '-';
echo $data['cdrs'][0]['destination_number'];
echo '-';
echo $data['cdrs'][0]['result'];
echo '-';
echo substr($data['cdrs'][0]['end_stamp'],0,10);
```

**MySql Insert Code:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO talep (test)  VALUES ('$test')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

you can use cron job which will run script revery 5 seconds

for more info on cron job , you can have a look at https://kb.iweb.com/hc/en-us/articles/230244168-Setting-up-cron-jobs-with-cPanel

important thing is, you should check if record exists in database or not and then insert in database.. for example, you have 1,2,3 records  in your file used in $json.. now these 3 records will be inserted in dsatabase. After 5 seconds, if there are 2 more records added... now $json have total  5 records and out of these 5 , first 3 are already inserted in database 5 seconda before.. so you will need to check if first 3 records are already in db, so only record number 4 and 5 should be inserted... other wise you wil get previous 3 + new 5 (including first 3) records = 8 records in db with duplicate rows...